# Firebase: Convert Json string with html tags to html

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been researching for almost 2 hours now to get a simple solution of how I could easily convert a json string having html tags so that the converted string can then be rendered on a web-page without printing the tags in raw format.

This string `<h1>Magazine Heading</h1>`as stored in firebase in json format, displays on my web page without any change:`<h1>Magazine Heading</h1>`

I have tried using the jQuery Library's: `JSON.parseJSON();` function, but it still doesn't work. There are so many questions and topics on this, but none are direct and effective.

NB: Not a duplicate question...other answers in related questions are too complex and vague.

Comment: What is not working? That seems pretty vague

Comment: JSON.parseJSON() function did not parse the original json string. Thus, the h1 tags were still showing when I rendered the string on the webpage...but I gotten the answer from @fzzle

Comment: Your question does not even contain any json, therefore it is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

First, to parse JSON you can use `JSON.parse()`. Second, to insert the HTML into an element you can use `element.innerHTML`. In your case:

```
element.innerHTML = '<h1>Magazine Heading</h1>';
```

Answer (score -2):

After parseing your JSON string. You can parse this and other xml/html results using jquery's parseXML.

```
var xml = "<h1>Magazine Heading</h1>", 
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$h1 = $xml.find( "h1" );

var text = $h1.text();
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

It might seem like overkill, but you can use this to parse the simplest html to very complex ones.

Comment: jQuery doesn't make everything *perfect*. OP hasn't tagged it in the first place. You don't need a ~92KB library to use about ~2KB (2.1%) of its code.

Comment: @Adam Azad. The OP mentions that he's using JQuery to parse JSON.